# Angular translator not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, ngx-translate

I am developing a project in Angular 4 with multiple languages. For this I use translator. First, I install `ngx-translator` and then start my work. I am getting the error:

> GET http://eluxer.net/code?sesscheck=1&id=105&subid=50932_2852_

This is my button, on click I'm passing a parameter to a function. Parameters are the same as in assets folder and i18n JSON file is present.

What's going wrong?

```js
{ TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
  this is imported in app.module.ts TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
      deps: [HttpClient],
    }
  })
  export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
```

```html
<button (click)="switchLanguage('ar')">
    <img src="/assets/images/saudi_arabian_flag.png" />
</button>
```

Comment: I would check browser for malware, that URL looks just like that. Try another browser and see if that domain comes up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely the eluxur injection virus. entry/MW:BLK:2 Either your browser/pc is infected or the website itself.